# Can Orchard do this?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Can I have a content manager Orchard site that manages two modules, each of them of a different looking (themed) site ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do your mean "Is it possible for a single orchard application to have 2 tenants (2 sites) with different themes"? If so, the answer is yes :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is what you mean, but you can have multiple sites running on the same Orchard application with different themes on.

You can do this simply by enabling the Multitenancy feature in your orchard's module page.